# How do I write a better regexp for css minification in php?

Tags: php, css, regex, minify

### What I have

I have the following regexp in php that minifies a raw css string:

```
function compress( $css ) {
    $css = str_replace('; ',';', $css);
    $css = str_replace(': ',':', $css);
    $css = str_replace(', ',',', $css);

    $css = str_replace(' }','}', $css);
    $css = str_replace('} ','}', $css);

    $css = str_replace('{ ','{', $css);
    $css = str_replace(' {','{', $css);

    $css = str_replace('( ','(', $css);
    $css = str_replace(' (','(', $css);

    $css = str_replace(' )',')', $css);
    $css = str_replace(') ',')', $css);

    $css = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n","\t",'  ','    ','    '),"",preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!','',$css));

    return $css;
}
```

This works, but is terrible code.

### Question

Does anybody know of a better way to write this?

Comment: Why not using an existing css minification library ?

Comment: why are you replacing closed brackets with opening ones?

Comment: @dystroy Usually they are just too big. I just want a couple of lines of simple code.

Comment: @GarethCornish My bad, fixed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been through this a bunch of times, and currently I have an implementation that is working well.

```
// comments
$string = preg_replace('!/\*.*?\*/!s','', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/\n\s*\n/',"\n", $string);

// space
$string = preg_replace('/[\n\r \t]/',' ', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/ +/',' ', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/ ?([,:;{}]) ?/','$1',$string);

// trailing;
$string = preg_replace('/;}/','}',$string);
```

I have this implemented as a Twig filter: https://github.com/catchamonkey/CatchamonkeyAsseticFilterBundle

Comment: I think i will swith to that solution too : )

Comment: This solution can break every css selector like this one: `div[style="width: 6px; height: 10px"]`

Comment: @350D Hi, yes you could well be right there. That sort of selector though probably highlights bigger issues than needing minification though.

Comment: some refinements: https://3v4l.org/fL9aH

Answer (score 2):

How about changing this code:

```
...
$css = str_replace('; ',';', $css);
$css = str_replace(': ',':', $css);
$css = str_replace(', ',',', $css);

$css = str_replace(' }','}', $css);
$css = str_replace('} ','}', $css);

$css = str_replace('{ ','{', $css);
$css = str_replace(' {','{', $css);
...
```

to this:

```
$css = str_replace(array('; ',': ',', ',...),array(';',':',',',...),$css);
```

Also consider using an existing library for CSS minification. There are many things, that can be minified. For example: `margin:0 0 0 0;` can become `margin:0;` and so on...

Comment: This is a a great answer and an educating one but I'm going with [catchamonkey's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/167470/catchamonkey) answer as it is more relevant to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use this for css:

```
//Minify CSS code:
function minifyCSS($sCss) {
    // Compress whitespace.
    $sCss = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $sCss);
    // Remove comments.
    $sCss = preg_replace('/\/\*.*?\*\//', '', $sCss);

    return trim($sCss);
}
```

Comment: This is good, but misses a lot of spaces that could be removed.